# Как в PHPStorm переименовать название метода во всех файлах?

Tags: phpstorm

Есть метод hasProjects я хочу чтобы теперь он во всех файлах назывался hasActiveProjects. Как мне можно это сделать? В сети пишут про рефакторинг, но деталей куда щелкать что конкретно делать нет.

Comment: Ctrl+shift+R - замена во всех файлах.

Comment: **Refactor > Rename** на методе

Comment: Спасибо это помогло

Answer (score 0):

shift+f6
должно помочь сразу  !

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]